# Django project not found Error

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm getting the error: django project not found when I try to run my bash script below, why?

This works: `gunicorn wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:8003`

This errors: `bash start_gunicorn.sh`

**start_gunicorn.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

LOGFILE=/srv/domain/logs/domain.log

ERRORFILE=/srv/domain/logs/error.log

LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)

NUM_WORKERS=3

#The below address:port info will be used later to configure Nginx with Gunicorn

ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:8003

# user/group to run as

#USER=your_unix_user

#GROUP=your_unix_group

cd /srv/domain

test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR

exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS \

--log-level=debug \

--log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE  1>>$ERRORFILE  &
```

Do I need to tell it where the project is? whats the setting for this?

**Stack:**

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 62, in make_default_env
    raise RuntimeError("django project not found")
RuntimeError: django project not found
2014-04-02 10:13:56 [1038] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1038)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn_django", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn_django')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 160, in run
    DjangoApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [SETTINGS_PATH]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 203, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 298, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 341, in stop
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 452, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
ubuntu@ip-10-37-235-227:/srv/domain$ sudo nano start_gunicorn.sh
```

Project Folder Example: Ubuntu

```
/srv/domain/manage.py
/srv/domain/wsgi.py
/srv/domain/project_folder/
/srv/domain/project_folder/apps/
/srv/domain/project_folder/core/
/srv/domain/project_folder/core/urls.py

etc
```

Comment: Which line tells about your project location ?

Comment: @Priyank Patel I'll update OP

Comment: @Priyank Patel so does there need to be one in the bash script? what is this setting?

Comment: Wondering... `gunicorn /srv/domain/wsgi.py` isn't sufficient ?

Comment: @PriyankPatel are you saying that I could use "gunicorn wsgi:application" within my start script instead and that it's production safe?

Comment: yes. Till its not accessible to public.

Comment: @PriyankPatel I just tried "exec gunicorn_django -w $NUM_WORKERS --bind=$ADDRESS" etc in my bash files and it gives the same error?

Comment: yes. thats for number of worker threads and port binding . but where u executing wsgi file of your project ?

Comment: I'm not, can I do that in the start_script?

Comment: yes. see last answer : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416172/how-can-i-modify-procfile-to-run-gunicorn-process-in-a-non-standard-folder-on-he`

Comment: @PriyankPatel what about this: "exec gunicorn wsgi:application" this seems to work. is this ok to use?

Comment: yes. its ok to use . but for production , u don't want to execute execute this script each time . so u should put it in `init.d` as services. you can google it .

Comment: thanks can you add an answer for me to accpect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your bash script , you can run your django project by simply writing following script :

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn /srv/domain/wsgi.py
```

It will run in default port . if you want to add logging ,workers threads and custom port then u can specify with arguments of `gunicorn` cmd . see [Gunicorn Ref](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/develop/configure.html) .

Now in production you don't want to run this script each time . so you can put it in `/etc/init.d/` . so it will run on startup . See [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)