# How to run a flask app from routes.py

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

[image]

I am working on a flask app with a structure as in the screenshot based on http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework--net-28822. To get this working locally I've been running the routes.py file:

```
$ python C:/envs/r2/mini/intro_to_flask/routes.py
C:\envs\virtalenvs\flask_mini\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:800: Use
rWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabl
ed by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be
 disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Which works normally . I'm now trying to deploy on heroku using gunicorn following https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud330/deploy. Following the directions, My requirements.txt contains:

```
$ pip Freeze
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==1.0.11
WTForms==2.1
Werkzeug==0.11.3
blinker==1.4
gunicorn==19.4.5
itsdangerous==0.24
```

routes.py:

```
from flask import render_template, request, flash, session, url_for, redirect
from forms import ContactForm, SignupForm, SigninForm
from flask.ext.mail import Message, Mail
from models import db, User

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

....... code ........

app.run()
```

I'm not sure what to put into my Procfile , I've tried several variations  including:

```
web: gunicorn runserver:app
```

The heroku logs show:

```
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910512+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     from intro_to_flask import
routes
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910513+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/intro_to_flask/rou
tes.py", line 123, in <module>
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910513+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     app.run()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910514+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910515+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     run_simple(host, port, self
, **options)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910515+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in run_simple
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910516+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     inner()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910516+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 654, in inner
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910517+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     fd=fd)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910518+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 548, in make_server
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910518+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     passthrough_errors, ssl_con
text, fd=fd)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910519+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 462, in __init__
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910523+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     HTTPServer.__init__(self, (
host, int(port)), handler)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910524+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 420, in __init__
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910525+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.server_bind()
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910526+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     SocketServer.TCPServer.serv
er_bind(self)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910527+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 434, in server_bind
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910528+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     self.socket.bind(self.serve
r_address)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910529+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib
/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910529+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     return getattr(self._sock,n
ame)(*args)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910548+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m error: [Errno 98] Address alrea
dy in use
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:56.910686+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [2016-01-23 19:14:56 +0000] [10
] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
←[36m2016-01-23T19:14:57.199826+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting
to up
```

Can anyone advise me on how to get this running?

Comment: I think you need `gunicorn route:app` because you create `app` in `route.py` but `route.py` has to be in the same folder as `Procfile`. Maybe `gunicorn intro_to_flask/route:app` will work. Better install gunicorn on local computer to learn how to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416172/how-can-i-modify-procfile-to-run-gunicorn-process-in-a-non-standard-folder-on-he

Comment: I ended up using Procfile: "web: gunicorn intro_to_flask.routes:app" and changing routes.py to if __name__ == '__main__': app.run().This works but I'm not sure why.