# Couldn't find that process type, Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple python bot on Heroku but I get the error
`couldn't find that process type`

When I try to scale the dynos. I already made a procfile and it looks like this:
`web: gunicorn dep:app`, where "dep" is the name of my python code

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 63):

This may happen if your procfile is misspelt, such as "procfile" or "ProcFile" etc. The file name should be "Procfile" (with a capital P).

sometimes changing the file name is not anough, because git wouldn't spot the change. I had to delete the Procfile completely, then commit the change, than add it again with the right name, and then commit that again:

1. remove your procfile
2. git commit
3. add a new procfile with the exact name "Procfile"
4. commit again
5. `git push heroku master` (or `main` - new heroku projects now uses `main`)

should work!

Comment: To make things clear: there should be no extension to this file (no `.txt` or whatever). just `Procfile`.

Comment: Very minute detail. but committed the same mistake and scratching my head . Your answer worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

Make Sure Procfile should not have any extension like .txt
otherwise this will be the error

`remote: -----> Discovering process types
 remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)`

To create file without extension type following in cmd 
 `notepad Procfile.`

Now add `web: gunicorn dep:app` and save
Now when you will git push heroku master the above lines will be like

`remote: -----> Discovering process types
 remote:        Procfile declares types -> web`

And the error is gone when you will run

C:\Users\Super-Singh\PycharmProjects\URLShortener>`heroku ps:scale web=1`

`Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free`

Comment: This worked for me but when I open the application I still have "Application error" and I also get "Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect..." in my logs. Please help.
Edit: Just realized I am on Linux so might be different

Answer (score 6):

Ensure that the Procfile is in the root directory of your repository.

In my case I had initially kept the Procfile in a subdirectory. Moving it to the root directory solved the problem.

For people who are trying to deploy a django web app, take note that the above step may cause another issue - of heroku unable to reach till the wsgi file residing in the subdirectory.

I solved it by referring to the below thread -

[How can I modify Procfile to run Gunicorn process in a non-standard folder on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416172/how-can-i-modify-procfile-to-run-gunicorn-process-in-a-non-standard-folder-on-he)

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me.

As per [this Heroku help page](https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos):

> **To fix:**
>
> Remove the existing buildpacks with `heroku buildpacks:clear`.
>   You will need to add an empty commit and redeploy for the changes to
>   take effect:
>
> `git commit --allow-empty -m "Adjust buildpacks on Heroku"`
>
> `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 1):

You might check your python version. I tried to deploy my Django project so my procfile looks like this `web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -` and I also got the same error `couldn't find that process type`.  and I found that [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes) only support python-3.6.4 and python-2.7.14 while I just had python3.5. You can type:

```
python -V
```

to see what python version you are using now. if not, you can download python 3.6. I followed this [How do I install Python 3.6 using apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get)

> Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04
>
> If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, you can use Felix Krull's
>   deadsnakes PPA at
>   https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install python3.6`
>
> Alternatively, you can use J Fernyhough's PPA at
>   https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6`
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> `sudo apt-get install python3.6`

and remember to keep you python 3.5. Don't remove it. and specify your python version in the runtime.txt file: `python-3.6.4` and run:

`heroku ps:scale web=1 --app [my app's name]`

and the problem solved. I hope my answer might help you.

Comment: Still can't find process type web -- help?

Answer (score 1):

In My case the error was solved by just creating space between web and gunicorn

**Before:**
web:gunicorn --pythonpath app app.wsgi

**After:**
web: gunicorn --pythonpath app app.wsgi

Answer (score 0):

While it's not Python, in my case, I had `heroku/java` followed by `heroku/pgbouncer`. In Heroku's Settings, I switched them so `heroku/pgbouncer` was on top. This fixed the issue. Perhaps your buildpacks need to be ordered differently if you are using multiple.