# couldn't find that process type

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I am having trouble with the "couldn't find that process type" error on Heroku. I submitted a ticket Thursday but still don't have a solution and they are not open for folks like me on the weekend, so I am posting here.

Please note:

1. This is a Django app
2. It runs locally on *both* heroku local and django runserver, but not heroku itself.
3. I was following a solution I read here:
   [Couldn't find that process type, Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512013/couldnt-find-that-process-type-heroku)
   which was to take the Procfile out, do a commit, then put it back, and do a commit, and it should work.

The output from the push to Heroku was the same:

```
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
```

So Heroku didn't even notice that the `Procfile` was missing?!

Then I put the `Procfile` back and I still get the same error:

```
2019-06-08T18:49:34.853568+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=lj-stage.herokuapp.com request_id=d592d4e6-7558-4003-ab55-b3081502f5cf fwd="50.203.248.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

I've also read about multiple buildpacks needing to be in a certain order, which might cause this error, but I only have one:

```
(hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie/hattie$ heroku buildpacks
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.7.8 to 7.24.4
=== lj-stage Buildpack URL
heroku/python
```

Furthermore, I did a word search through the Python buildpack on GitHub and didn't see anything to indicate the buildpack is doing anything other than rely on the `Procfile` for process types.

I also tried `heroku ps:scale web=1`, which gives the 'couldn't find that process type' error.

There are several other similar questions here on SO, a lot of them don't have answers, and I tried the ones that did. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

update:
As requested, here is my tree. The names next to Procfile are Django models:

```
hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie$ tree -L 2

├── =2.2
├── hattie
│   ├── academy
│   ├── account
│   ├── airflow_tutorial_script.py
│   ├── bar
│   ├── bench
│   ├── caseAT
│   ├── codeAT
│   ├── commentaryAT
│   ├── consultant
│   ├── contact_form
│   ├── government
│   ├── hattie
│   ├── hattie.sublime-project
│   ├── hattie.sublime-workspace
│   ├── How It Works - Sort Sequences
│   ├── legislature
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── pac
│   ├── people
│   ├── post
│   ├── Procfile
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── templates
│   └── utilities
├── hattie pipenv
├── pipenv for refactor4
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── refactor4.sublime-project
└── refactor4.sublime-workspace
```

And here is the content of my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hattie.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `Procfile`. We can't help without that.

Comment: And show the directory structure: possibly the Procfile is in the wrong place.

Comment: @MalikA.Rumi, Daniel was right: your `Procfile` is in the wrong place. It must be in the root of your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`Procfile` must be in the root of your repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location). Move it there and redeploy.

Comment: I moved it down a level, so it was next to settings. Then I moved up two levels, so it was next to Pipfile. In both cases, I still get the same error. remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
2019-06-08T22:24:44.841430+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lj-stage.herokuapp.com request_id=0da0a4ea-0c44-4e0b-b524-d1e9d1f0ce50 fwd="50.203.248.222" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: (hattie-nHCNXwaX) malikarumi@Tetuoan2:~/Projects/hattie/hattie$ heroku ps:scale web=1
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.7.8 to 7.24.4
Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).

Comment: If your `Procfile` is where it's supposed to be, and named correctly (exactly `Procfile`, with that capitalization and no extension) it should work. It may need to have a Unix line ending, so try that.

Comment: Yes, I got it all fixed now. The problem was I had an *extra* folder wrapping my root directory. I merged that and everything is fine now. Thanks!