# Heroku Spring Boot deploy not creating database tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api, rest, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot REST API to Heroku.

It successfully uploads the files to Heroku's Git repository.

But it is not creating the database tables and so the app doesn't work.

This is how I'm doing on the CLI.

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
heroku login
heroku create myappname
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
git push heroku main
```

Tried with several different application.properties (as below) and none of them was successful.
(user/passwords below are fake. Just for explanation purpose)

application.properties test1

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

application.properties test2

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

application.properties test3

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=postgres://aooswjxdniusmd:f99447ede191d139d32f1e3d539dc8ty4535c65350a51960d887km44d6we7c4@ec2-21-567-987-345.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/q5kl3s76jh08yt
```

application.properties test4

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=postgres://aooswjxdniusmd:f99447ede191d139d32f1e3d539dc8ty4535c65350a51960d887km44d6we7c4@ec2-21-567-987-345.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/q5kl3s76jh08yt
```

application.properties test5

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=info
```

application.properties test6

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

application.properties test7

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=info
```

UPDATE:

I ran `heroku logs --tail` to take a look at the logs.

Two entries called my attention:

`heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

`Error: Unable to access jarfile target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Then I tried the following:

`java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Also got the same error message:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

So that seems to be the cause of the issue.

Not sure why it is happening though.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on without looking at the startup logs for Spring Boot. Maybe it cannot connect to your remote SQL cluster?

Comment: @A M I added to the question some error messages I got from the log. Not sure why that's happening.

Comment: Well it seems that the JAR file cannot be found possibly because it is generated with a different name when `mvn package` is called. Maybe try calling JAR by using `java -jar target/*.jar` instead of the specific name. By default, Maven would generate the JAR inside target folder.

Comment: @A M Now I ran the following: ```java -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar``` It did find the jar file and executed it. Some other error showed up, but not the "Unable to access jarfile" which is the one that is being generated in heroku. The only difference is that now I added the folder target to the command. And on heroku error logs it does show the target folder: ```Error: Unable to access jarfile target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar``` So now question becomes why heroku is not finding the file.

Comment: If you are running that command locally, it might work because the JAR has been generated in the target folder if you check that. I do not know what your Procfile looks like or if it is autogenerated but you can check out this answer and see if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60215244/2081730

Comment: @A M I tried some of the configurations from the link you provided. With procfile I kept getting ```Error: Unable to access jarfile target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```. Then I removed procfile and also removed ```<packaging>``` from pom.xml like suggested in the link. That did remove the old ```No web processes running``` message. But still doesn't run the app. The error now is ```State changed from crashed to down``` Procfile I tried had the following content: ```web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=default -jar target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```

Comment: @A M Noted another thing. When I do a git clone, it downloads the code from heroku but it doesn't download the .jar file. So wondering if the jar file is really being pushed to heroku and if that should happen at all.

Comment: your problem could be that you are pushing your code to a branch named "main" and Heroku by default works with master so in your case, it wouldn't find anything to deploy on master. So maybe try pushing to master?

You could also look here in the Maven plugin section :
https://stackabuse.com/deploying-spring-boot-applications-to-heroku/

Comment: @A M I got it to work! Just removed the app from heroku and created a new one with the same name. Now everything that was not working, now works. So I think the first one was corrupted in some way. One thing that also leads me to believe that, is that when the app was accessed on the url it would show a "Application error". Now, even before deploying the code and creating the db it shows a "Heroku | Welcome to your new app!". Deploying to main is not the problem. Heroku supports that. In fact it is migrating from master to main just like github.https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1829