# heroku ps:scale web=1 Scaling dynos... Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I am making my portfolio python django website, while deploying I am getting an error

I am trying to type this

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

and I am getting this error

```
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

my Profile has this command only...

```
web: gunicorn Hello.wgsi
```

please help  me out I want to show my class teacher this portfolio webpage but it would be very shameful to show her a locally hosted website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512013/couldnt-find-that-process-type-heroku

Comment: "my Profile has this command only"—it's not `Profile`, but _`Procfile`_. "Proc" for "process", as this file defines your processes.