# Heroku error during Django website deployment

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I'm still getting this error after all the steps follow trying to solve.
Can anyone help me pls.

this is the **error** obtained from my PowerShell:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

This is the content of my **Procfile** located in my root:

```
��web :  gunicorn grouppublishingindia.wsgi --log-file -
```

The error I'm getting from my browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Procfile is in the root directory of your repository.

This may happen if your procfile is misspelt, such as "procfile" or "ProcFile" etc. The file name should be "Procfile" (with a capital P).

[From elons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184918/11282077).