# "Couldn't find that process type (web)." when deploying to Heroku from Django

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

Trying to deploy my Django application on Heroku. When I try to add Dyno's, heroku ps:scale web=1, it gives me an error message stating "Couldn't find that process type (web)." I double checked the name of Procfile, the location, and the content, and it all appears correct. Any ideas? I attached a screen shot of my directory and the content.

I have no clue what could be incorrect with this. Anyone have any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skokn.png)

Comment: Move your `Procfile` up one directory so it's beside your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Couldn't find that process type, Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48512013/couldnt-find-that-process-type-heroku)