# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blogpro.wsgi' in Procfile, Deploying Django using Heroku, code H10 : App crashed

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I am trying to deploy django project on Heroku, it is not deploying iam getting error as follows:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blogpro.wsgi

see full detail error in log.

[Full deatil log error - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBadc.png)

```
2021-07-30T06:58:08.676208+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blogpro.wsgi'
2021-07-30T06:58:08.676489+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-07-30 06:58:08 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
```

my Procfile content is :

```
web: gunicorn blogpro.wsgi
```

and see my Procfile location folder in image below :

[Procfile location image - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvLv.png)

iam not able to understand what problem is ? is it because of my procfile in wrong location (if your answer is procfile should be in root directory please specify the root directory because i don't know what root directory is)? and whether the problem is in content of Procfile ? please see all images attached to see problem clearly.

Comment: Possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430579/11544538). Btw, I had a similar problem and as a workaround I pasted `cd <project_folder> &&` before `gunicorn`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ersain . Your possible answer link helped me, and solved my issue. according to it Procfile content should be "web: gunicorn --pythonpath blogpro blogpro.wsgi". Once again thanks a lot.